# XML Time PHP Convert

Tags: php, xml, time, date-formatting

I can get the day and month displaying fine but my issue is with the time.  In the XML file I am given it is set out as:

```
<Start>2012-11-11T01:00:00Z</Start>
<End>2012-11-11T02:00:00Z</End>
```

but the final style should be 2pm - 3pm and my time zone is NZ

Comment: how did you try to display it.

Comment: you need to convert it to that style? in NZ zone?

Comment: @Reflective I think so as we now are daylight savings and the times should be forward an hour.  I also need to show it am or pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = "2012-11-11T01:00:00Z";
$end = "2012-11-11T02:00:00Z";
echo date("Ga", strtotime($start)) . "\n";
echo date("Ga", strtotime($end));
```

Output :

```
1am

2am
```

Refer to the doc : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I have done the above and it gave me the correct time on my dev server yet to try on live site could be a php issue